# File System access in Windows Phone using PhoneGap

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to Windows Phone (using PhoneGap). Where does the created file get stored when we do a File Write  using PhoneGap? I also need to retrieve the storage path on the phone.

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);    
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.notification.alert("Device Ready");
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.APPLICATION, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }
    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("TextFile3.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
        navigator.notification.alert("gotFS");
    }
    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
        navigator.notification.alert("gotFileEntry");
    }
    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        navigator.notification.alert("gotFileWriter");
        writer.onwriteend = function (evt) {
            console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
            writer.truncate(11);
            writer.onwriteend = function (evt) {
                console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
                writer.seek(4);
                writer.write(" different text");
                writer.onwriteend = function (evt) {
                    console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
                    navigator.notification.alert("gotFileWriterEnd");
                }
            };
        };
        writer.write("some sample text");

    }
    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe any Windows Phone 7 devices have access to the SD card so this isn't going to be possible.

Comment: Hi Paul,Actually iam trying with above code,but iam not able to find out whether it get created or not,file path also where it was created?Thank you.

Comment: Work through the following and then port this over to methods that you can invoke from your PhoneGap project : http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage

Comment: thank you Paul,actually i want to see the location of files/folders which got created in our phone emulator.how can i see the physical file?thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No devices have access to the SD card directly, the mechanism used to Save/Load persistent data is via the IsolatedStorage API's.

You can find a detailed explanation here : [MSDN - Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx)

For an example see the post by Jeff Blankenburg from the 31 Days of Windows Phone series, it has a brief overciew of the general concept and provides code examples for implementation. : [31 Days of Windows Phone - Isolated Storage.](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/)

Comment: Thank you Jamie,
Actually here iam using Phonegap for windows mobile development.so can u give the storage path or simple example to save files in windows mobile SD-card.

Thank you

Comment: @AkilPandu You may not understand Jamie's correct answer. The phone provides **absolutely zero** ability to access the SD-card. PhoneGap is a platform that runs on top of the windows phone SDK, meaning that it **also** cannot access the SD-Card. To reiterate: THERE IS NO WAY THAT THIS CAN BE DONE. Also (and this is more of an opinion, please please please please develop your windows phone apps natively. There are some problems with providing good UI using PhoneGap on Windows Phone. Sure, you can develop apps quickly for three platforms, but at the (all too high) cost of quality.

Comment: @AkilPandu As Paul said, there's no way this can be done without using the Isolated Storage API.

Comment: thank you,but i need to store some files in windows phone storage.can u give any example to do that.

Comment: hi jamie i posted my code above just have a look.I hope u get some idea from the added code snippet.can u please help me how to find the path of the file to know whether it got created or not.

Comment: In order to create the file in the first place you should know the path...? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually it is working fine which i posted the code above,but iam not able to find out where the file is creating.Here iam doing sample in phonegap(windows mobile)!So here i need the file path.

Comment: I imagine the method used to save a file is just a 'wrapper' of sorts that will store in within the phone's isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you'd probably use one of the [PhoneGap Storage APIs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage). Most likely [`localStorage`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage), which the docs state "provides an interface to a W3C Storage interface" and indicates that it's supported on Windows Phone 7.

Now this isn't saying that it's going to save to some specific "SD Card" (my phone doesn't even have one), but I assume it will save to Isolated Storage.

Comment: Thank you,actually i want to create and read a textfile in our windows mobile(phonegap),can u pls give me sample code.